# TDD code coverage status

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, code-coverage

My overall code coverage for my project is 72.86% with 106 failed test cases, 1 skipped test cases and 925 passed test cases. A total of 1032 test cases. Inside the coverage got 4 sub coverage which are:

1. BusinessLogic.dll :67.72%
2. datalogic.dll :18.83%
3. dataobject.dll :50.00%
4. testbusinesslogic.dll :86.01%

I only get to know with the testbusinesslogic.dll, and make the test pass.
I have no idea with the rest (Business.dll/datalogic.dll/dataobject.dll) because I cannot debug the method.

1. how do I increase the percentage of my code coverage in that area?
2. Can I edit the code at there?
3. What should I do to make the test pass?
4. Or the rest of 106 failed test case in only at the "testbusinesslogic.dll"?
5. If I passed all the test cases, then will the 3 sub code coverage be increased? (if the test case only are in the testbusinesslogic.dll)

This is my very 1st time to do the TDD.

Below are 1 of the methods in datalogic.dll file, this method does not appear in my failed/passed/skipped test case. What does this means? Why the code coverage for this section will be so low? How to increase the code coverage for the datalogic.dll section? Since I have no failed test case which allow me to make it pass like testbusinesslogic.dll

```
public void GetModelDataForCreate(DataSet availabilityDataSet, int resourceID)
    {

        Database db = WindowsApplicationTemplate.ApplicationDatabase.DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

        string sqlProcedure = "uspAvailabilityGetModelDataForCreate";
        DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sqlProcedure);
        UtilityDL.SetCommandTimeout(dbCommand);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "resourceID", DbType.Int32, resourceID);

        string[] tables = new string[] { "EventType", "LaborCategory", "Event", "IntelTime", "DurationType", "Resource", "ParameterInfo" };

        availabilityDataSet.Clear();

        // RETRIEVE DATA FROM DB AND LOAD INTO DATASET
        db.LoadDataSet(dbCommand, availabilityDataSet, tables);

    }
```

Comment: I am confused as to what you are asking.  To increase the code coverage, you write more tests.  To make tests pass, you fix the code.

Comment: i have thousand test cases, while if 100% code coverage does not mean that the code cover all. My problem is how to increase the (1)/(2)/(3) sub code coverage, since the % at there is low. Is that the same way as "testbusinesslogic.dll"? Because I can debug and find the error at the "testbusinesslogic.dll" then passed the test. However, I cannot do that for the rest 3 sub code coverage. Correct me if I am wrong. This is just what I have experienced for now. =)

Answer (score 7):

So, first things first: You aren't doing TDD correctly. In TDD, there should only ever be one failed test at a time - the one you are writing code for.

(There can be others when you hit a re-factoring frenzy point and introduce new defects, but those are acute events that are quickly resolved.)

This is a side-effect of TDD, not a goal. The process that you use and the actions that you take in TDD lead to this state of being.

TDD is very much a learned skill. Tutorials will get you started but to become proficient requires a lot of practice. But don't lose heart! It is quite pleasant to develop TDD expertise if you do so on real work. The contrived examples that are used to illustrate TDD are predictably boring and useless and frequently wrong.

Next, regarding test coverage, you don't want to include `testbusinesslogic` in the aggregate number. You can exclude the entire DLL by using attributes specific to the testing tool. For MSTest, the information is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159530.aspx in the **Excluding / Including** section.

Also, many failed tests can lower code coverage when the tests fail because exceptions are thrown within the code under test, which causes the following code to never be executed during the test. If you have a lot of these, odds are that your test setup is incorrect.

And finally, you will not be successful overall unless you can edit the code in the DLLs. The point of testing is to correct defects. Testing code that you cannot touch is kinda useless.

Comment: yes, I am on the way to solve the fail test case, but I just curious is that I just have to solve all the fail test cases in testbusinesslogic.dll? How about BusinessLogic.dll :67.72%, datalogic.dll :18.83%, dataobject.dll :50.00%. These 3 section does not throw me any fail test case or error? How to I find out what happen behind the code to make these section get a low % of code coverage?

Answer (score 0):

Test coverage reports how much of your code is being executed while running the tests.

The coverage of your test assembly testbusinesslogic.dll is irrelevant (but I find it weird it's not reaaaaally close to a 100%, might look into why this is the case). What might be a good indicator is the coverage % of your other (production) assemblies.

If you want to get higher coverage for these production assemblies, you need to **write more tests in testbusinesslogic.dll** yourself that execute the uncovered code there. That's the only way to get their test coverage up.

Note: unit testing "just to increase code coverage" is generally a bad idea. Write tests to have a safety net, regression tests, drive the design or whatever. But writing tests just to get some arbitrary percentage up will reap little to no benefits.

As Keith Payne stated, you might be doing Test-First development (your unit tests exist before the production code), but you're not really doing Test-**Driven** Development.